# Default initialize a class with many boolean values?

Tags: c++, initialization

**Note:** I can not use c++11.

I have a class with many boolean values and a string. It is expected to be used on the stack. Right now I use this:

```
class Lorem: public Ipsulum {
public:
Lorem() :
    has_foo(0),
    is_bar(0),
    is_on(0),
    is_a_pony(0),
    has_car(0),
    foorbar()         // do I need this line if "foobar" is std::string?
{ }

private:
    bool has_foo;
    bool is_bar;
    bool is_off;
    bool is_a_pony;
    bool has_car;
    std::string foobar;  
}
```

**Question 1:** Is there a way to do this simpler?

**Question 2:** Do I have to include the "foorbar" initializer in the list?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ isn't "default" only available since c++11?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ No, that is completely wrong (except for `foobar`.)

Comment: @user10607 You are right, pre c++11 this behavior wasn't guaranteed. There's not simpler way, to initialize the values properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this simpler?

I guess you mean, is there a way to avoid initialising each `bool` individually? You could put them inside a structure, and value-initialise that:

```
Lorem() : flags() {}

private:
struct Flags {
    bool has_foo;
    bool is_bar;
    bool is_off;
    bool is_a_pony;
    bool has_car;
} flags;
```

or wrap them in something that forces value-initialisation

```
template <typename T> struct value_init {
    value_init() : value() {}
    T value;
};

value_init<bool> has_foo;
```

or perhaps use `std::bitset` or similar.

> Do I have to include the "foorbar" initializer in the list?

No. That's a class type with a default constructor; that constructor will be used whether you explicitly value-initialise it, or leave it to be default-initialised.

Answer (score 3):

No, there is no simpler way, by the way it's probably more clear to use `false`, instead of `0`, when you initialize boolean variable.

There is no need of initialization of foobar, it will be constructed with default constructor, if you don't initialize it.

Answer (score -1):

```
class Lorem: public Ipsulum {
public:
Lorem() :
    has_foo(0),
    is_bar(0),
    is_on(0),
    is_a_pony(0),
    has_car(0),
    foorbar("")         // do I need this line if "foobar" is std::string?
{ }
```

it must works

Comment: The question was, could the code be made simpler? You've made it slightly more complicated.